# How do I add an object/this to a string in $$ selector in prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

```
$element = $(element);
console.log($$("#" + element + " > p")[0]); // works
console.log($$($element + $$(" > p"))[0]); // something like this
```

Comment: You're going to have to explain what it is you want to do, because that doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: I don't really have the id, I have element as an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `"#" + element.id` — though it seems a lot more sensible to write `$(element).select('p')`.

Comment: Note that the original question seems to want the immediate descendant `<p>` elements - I'm not exactly sure how you'd do that with "select".

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`select`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/select) method of the element itself:

```
$element.select('p')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm rusty at Prototype but I think that if you want to find all the `<p>` elements that are direct children of some element you've already got, you'd do this:

```
var firstPara = $(element).find(function(e) { return e.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'P'; });
```